# How can i optimize my sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, optimization

I have a problem. I have a sql query. query is so slow when i use order by distance. But if i dont use order by distance then query is fast. My query is:

```
SELECT     id,groupname,lat,lon,is_public,firma_kat,title,
           ((ACOS(SIN(41.06775100000000 * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + 
           COS(41.06775100000000 * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * 
           COS((29.00661300000000 - lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) 
           AS distance 
FROM       `groups` 
WHERE      id NOT IN(222330, 14302, 178547, 178563, 178572, 178571, 178573, 222328, 
                     222334, 222342, 222358, 222366, 222370, 222371, 222373, 222383, 
                     222384, 222396, 222419, 222438, 222539, 222553, 222555, 222563, 
                     222565, 222572, 222574, 222575, 222576, 222577, 222579, 222591, 
                     222592, 222594, 222613, 222711, 222630, 222632, 222653, 222657, 
                     222677, 222679, 222683, 222688, 222689, 222697, 222719, 222721, 
                     222727, 222728, 222735, 222736, 222737, 222744, 222746, 222749, 
                     222770, 222771, 222791, 222797, 222798, 222803, 222800, 222801, 
                     222802, 222804, 222805, 222806, 222807, 222808) 
HAVING     distance <= '100' 
ORDER BY   distance ASC LIMIT 0,50
```

Is there an alternative query for this query. Thank you.

Comment: What I would do is inserting directly the distance while inserting your table rows. Ordering would be much faster and you queries clearer.

Comment: I dont insert. because 41.06775100000000 and 29.00661300000000 are function parameter. distance varies according to the lat and lon values.

Comment: MMh I just understood. Pretty good problem Let me know if you find solution

Comment: Is it required to calculate your distance via sql or could you do it in the program which uses the data?

Comment: Kabulan0lak i will tell you when i find solution ;) Iralution, this sql list 50 companies near of a user. 41.06775100000000 and 29.00661300000000 values belonging to a user, and sql listing 50 company near from far for this user .

Comment: What I meant was you could query the data with the lon and lat values and perform the calculations in the application which is mostly performing faster than calculating via sql

Comment: What happen if you ORDER BY something like (lat - user_lat)² + (lon - user_lon)² ? Is you query faster ? And are the distances well ordered ?

Comment: Kabulan0lak it don calculate real distance. Because its calculate linear distance, but coordinates the slope between is important.

Comment: Something is wrong here -- apart from you are using HAVING instead of AND (you are not aggregating).   You are ordering by an arithmetic function of row variable only.  What is total result set without the limit?  The limit short circuits the rows fetch without the order but is only applied to the sorted results if the ORDER BY clause is included.

Answer (score 0):

It's your use of HAVING instead of a WHERE contraint.  Your construct is syntactically equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT     id,groupname,lat,lon,is_public,firma_kat,title,
               ((ACOS(SIN(41.06775100000000 * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + 
               COS(41.06775100000000 * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * 
               COS((29.00661300000000 - lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) 
               AS distance 
    FROM       `groups` 
    WHERE      id NOT IN(222330, 14302, 178547, 178563, 178572, 178571, 178573, 222328, 
                         222334, 222342, 222358, 222366, 222370, 222371, 222373, 222383, 
                         222384, 222396, 222419, 222438, 222539, 222553, 222555, 222563, 
                         222565, 222572, 222574, 222575, 222576, 222577, 222579, 222591, 
                         222592, 222594, 222613, 222711, 222630, 222632, 222653, 222657, 
                         222677, 222679, 222683, 222688, 222689, 222697, 222719, 222721, 
                         222727, 222728, 222735, 222736, 222737, 222744, 222746, 222749, 
                         222770, 222771, 222791, 222797, 222798, 222803, 222800, 222801, 
                         222802, 222804, 222805, 222806, 222807, 222808) 
) AS grp
WHERE grp.distance <= '100' 
ORDER BY grp.distance ASC LIMIT 0,50
```

Now do you see why it can run a *lot* slower?

### Addendum

Something like:

```
SELECT     id,groupname,lat,lon,is_public,firma_kat,title,
           ((ACOS(SIN(41.06775100000000 * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + 
           COS(41.06775100000000 * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * 
           COS((29.00661300000000 - lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) 
              AS distance 
FROM       `groups` 
WHERE      id NOT IN(222330, 14302, 178547, 178563, 178572, 178571, 178573, 222328, 
                     222334, 222342, 222358, 222366, 222370, 222371, 222373, 222383, 
                     222384, 222396, 222419, 222438, 222539, 222553, 222555, 222563, 
                     222565, 222572, 222574, 222575, 222576, 222577, 222579, 222591, 
                     222592, 222594, 222613, 222711, 222630, 222632, 222653, 222657, 
                     222677, 222679, 222683, 222688, 222689, 222697, 222719, 222721, 
                     222727, 222728, 222735, 222736, 222737, 222744, 222746, 222749, 
                     222770, 222771, 222791, 222797, 222798, 222803, 222800, 222801, 
                     222802, 222804, 222805, 222806, 222807, 222808) 
WHERE 
  long BETWEEN AAAA AND BBBB AND
  lat  BETWEEN BBBB AND DDDD AND
  distance <= '100' 
ORDER distance ASC LIMIT 0,50
```

if you precompute the AAAA ... DDDD to be the bounding rectangle *and* you have non-unique indexes on lat and long.  This will at least limit the rows to be read as well as those to be sorted

Comment: TerryE so thank you but your query was run 1.700 s and its so slow. My old query was running 0.9 s . And total row count 300000 without limit.

Comment: I didn't say this would run fast, just that its the syntactic equivalent of what you are trying to do, to help you under why it is so slow  The LIMIT clause limits the result set not the rows read to execute the query.  Do an EXPLAIN of the variants to see what I mean :)  **Don't use HAVING**